# Laravel path gets reset when closing my terminal

Tags: php, laravel, path, zsh

This is what is happening to me:

1. Opening Terminal
2. `laravel`
3. zsh: command not found: laravel
4. `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin`
5. `laravel`
6. Laravel works like normal now.

But when I close my Terminal or open a new window, the `laravel` command doesn't work. However, it does work after I enter the `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin` command again.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because you `export` only for the current terminal session. You need to add it to `.bashrc` or `.profile` or whatever your shell uses to add it permanently. Search the web for those

Comment: Add the `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin` to `~/.bashrc` then run `source ~/.bashrc` and you are good to go.

Comment: If you're using `zsh`, then you'd add this to `.zshrc`, and run source `.zshrc`, not `.bashrc` or `.profile`

Comment: It works now. I don't know how to mark this as answered but your comments solved this problem. Thanks.